# Not able to set multiple markers on the Google maps using Google map javascript api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

i want to place multiple markers on the map but I'm getting a map with no markers set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;
  var i;

  window.onload=function()
  {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
         var places =[];
         places.push(google.maps.LatLng(40.756,-73.986));
         places.push(google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002));
         places.push(google.maps.LatLng(37.775,-122.419));
         places.push(google.maps.LatLng(47.620,-122.347));
         places.push(google.maps.LatLng(-22.933,-43.184));
         for(i=0; i<places.length;i++)
      {
          var marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:places[i],map: map,title:'place Number'+i});

        bounds.extend(places[i]);

      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all your lines that look like this:

```
     places.push(google.maps.LatLng(40.756,-73.986));
```

To look like this:

```
     places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.756,-73.986));
```

Here's your code above with these modifications.  It's working for me.  Try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;
  var i;

  window.onload=function()
  {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
         var places =[];
         places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.756,-73.986));
         places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002));
         places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(37.775,-122.419));
         places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(47.620,-122.347));
         places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-22.933,-43.184));
         for(i=0; i<places.length;i++)
      {
          var marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:places[i],map: map,title:'place Number'+i});

        bounds.extend(places[i]);

      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've explicitly added what your modified code would look like to the answer.  Try cutting and pasting it.

Comment: I'm creating a java application and if I want to pass places[] as an argument to the function in the script(on jsp page), from another java page the do i need to use some php code or it can be done with javascript and only?                                            Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function and call after populate your results. Also you can use json push data from serverside to javascript

```
function showMap(locations){  
    //map code here
}
```